How is Fight/Flight decision by Karmic belief
In an individual's life when a person is confronted with temporary hardships too much to endure...how does one decide when to bear it as a prarabhdam or when to get rid of the source of pain by actively fighting it out ?
What governs a Fight or Flight choice? When is Flight chosen as pain bearer mode that has to be miserably sustained even if looked down upon by others in society as a weak submission leaving it God's justice scheme?
There is no accessible source to find individual or group karmic debit/credit balance according to karmic /dharmic principle criterion in any reference Rule Book to resolve individual dharma sandeham. If available there would be less tendency to make hasty decisions.  Even friendly counsels could be varied.
When taken to a level of groups: Lord Rama, an Avatar and king is a source of power so could proceed to avenge adharmic violence and later organize to win, whereas the nation  Bharat had to meekly lie low  bearing conquests from foreign soil  for centuries together, with only weak resistances even when culturally endowed with Karma belief towards tough reply action.
